# Partially copying NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, list-comprehension

I have a `NumPy` array which consists of over 40 columns. My objective is simply to create another array which has a subset of these columns and attaching data.

My code is:

```
RecDtypes = []
RecColIds = ['REC*','GLOBAL*']
for name in Reconciliation.dtype.names:
    for Id in RecColIds:    
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(name,Id):
            RecDtypes.append(name)
#Change column names
if RecDtypes:
    Rec = Reconciliation[RecDtypes]
    newnames=[]    
    for oldname in Rec.dtype.names:
        for Id in RecColIds:    
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(oldname,Id):
                newnames.append(oldname[len(Id):])
    Rec.dtype.names=newnames
```

Here, `Rec = new array` and `Reconciliation = old array`. The first loop extracts the columns I want out of the first array. The second loop renames the column names.

What is a more simple/efficient/concise way to do this?

Comment: This looks a bit like you're trying to use custom numpy types to achieve a table with headers.. It seems to me like you'd be much better off with pandas.

Comment: I see what you mean, however I require the new table to be in a numpy array format.

Comment: have you tested this? is it really that slow? the only large data copy (as far as I understand) is `Rec = Reconciliation[RecDtypes]` after that you're only working with the 40 or so column headers as strings.

Comment: maybe generate your new name in the same loop you find matches to eliminate a bit of extraneous code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a copy and rename task:

```
In [95]: dt = np.dtype('i,i,i,i')
In [96]: arr = np.zeros((2,), dtype=dt)
In [97]: arr[0]=np.arange(4)
In [98]: arr[1]=np.arange(4,8)
In [99]: arr
Out[99]: 
array([(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

Get a list of names that fits some pattern:

```
In [100]: alist = [name for name in dt.names if name[1] in ['1','3']]
In [101]: alist
Out[101]: ['f1', 'f3']
```

Make a straight forward copy by field name:

```
In [102]: arr1 = arr[alist]
In [103]: arr1
Out[103]: 
array([(1, 3), (5, 7)], 
      dtype=[('f1', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

And a straight forward field name change:

```
In [104]: arr1.dtype.names = ['one','three']
In [105]: arr1
Out[105]: 
array([(1, 3), (5, 7)], 
      dtype=[('one', '<i4'), ('three', '<i4')])
```

You many need to use `arr1 = arr[alist].copy()` if you intend to modify the values:

```
In [107]: arr1['one'] += 1
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: Numpy has detected that you (may be) writing to an array returned
by numpy.diagonal or by selecting multiple fields in a structured
array. This code will likely break in a future numpy release --
see numpy.diagonal or arrays.indexing reference docs for details.
The quick fix is to make an explicit copy (e.g., do
arr.diagonal().copy() or arr[['f0','f1']].copy()).
  #!/usr/bin/python3
```

### (earlier answer - may still be useful)

A sub module `numpy.lib.recfunctions` has functions for copying and modifying structured arrays and their names.  In general though, these functions work by creating an empty target array with the desired shape and dtype, and then copying values by field name from old to new.  That appears to be what you are doing.

Generally a structured array will have many rows, and relatively fewer fields.  So an iterative copy by fields is not that expensive.

You can access multiple fields at once with a list of names

```
arr[['f0','f1']]
```

edit - your `Reconciliation[RecDtypes]` is doing exactly this.  Fetching several fields at once.

But you may get a warning if you do anything but read those values, suggesting that you add a `copy`.  And recent `numpy` release notes have something about changing from a copy by name to a copy by position.

---

Illustrating the copy by field name:

```
In [128]: alist
Out[128]: ['f1', 'f3']
In [129]: arr
Out[129]: 
array([(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
In [130]: dt.descr
Out[130]: [('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')]
In [131]: dt1 = [item for item in dt.descr if item[0] in alist]
In [132]: dt1
Out[132]: [('f1', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')]
In [133]: res = np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype=dt1)
In [134]: for name in alist:
     ...:     res[name] = arr[name]   
In [135]: res
Out[135]: 
array([(1, 3), (5, 7)], 
      dtype=[('f1', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

`arr[alist].copy()` is simpler, and probably faster.

Answer (score 1):

From the description of your problem, I don't see how this would be too stressful computation wise (40 columns = 40 strings to test and move around). You can eliminate some clutter by combining your two loops, as they are effectively looping over the same lists. This also may have a slight performance benefit, but again from my first sentence it's probably negligible.

```
RecDtypes = []
newnames = []
RecColIds = ['REC*','GLOBAL*']
for name in Reconciliation.dtype.names:
    for Id in RecColIds:    
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(name,Id):
            RecDtypes.append(name)
            newnames.append(name[len(Id):])
#Change column names
if RecDtypes:
    Rec = Reconciliation[RecDtypes]
    Rec.dtype.names=newnames
```

Comment: without access to `Reconciliation` I'm unable to test, but this should work

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, I did find your post helpful also.